# Is it possible to load all ios CPU cores?

Tags: ios

Just want to understand the theoretical possibilities.
If I create many threads, can they be assigned to all cores (including Monsoon and Mistral) at the same time?
If not, how does OS make decision which cores it should use for the current task?

Comment: Unrelated: I think it has nothing to do with the used language (Swift), it is about the iOS runs apps.

Comment: Sorry, fixed. I have 1 day experience with IoS so have some issues with terminology